# Using streams through TcpClient and TcpServer

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcp, stream, streaming

I try to send data from server (TcpListener) to client (TcpClient). I use Windows Form Application and the next code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Server As TcpListener = Nothing
Private ServerThread As Thread = Nothing
Dim tcpclnt As TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream

Public Shared bytes(1024) As Byte
Public Shared data As String = Nothing


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 40000)
    ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionListener)
    ServerThread.IsBackground = True
    ServerThread.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = "Server started!"

End Sub

Private Sub ConnectionListener()
    Try
        Server.Start()


        While True
            Dim myClient As TcpClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf SomeClientActions)
            T.Start(myClient)
            Invoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Client connected")


            ' HERE IM TRYING TO READ DATA FROM STREAM
            stream = myClient.GetStream()
            Dim i As Int32
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            While True
                ' Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                Invoke(Sub() TextBox3.Text = "Received: {0}" + data)

                ' Process the data sent by the client.
                data = data.ToUpper()
                Dim msg As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                ' Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length)
                Invoke(Sub() TextBox3.Text = "Sent: {0}" + data)

                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

           End While


            myClient.Close()
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to Accept Connections", "Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
    Application.ExitThread()

End Sub

Private Sub SomeClientActions(ByVal client As Object)
    ' ... do something with "client" in here ...
    ' MAYBE SOME CODE HERE?..
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Server.Stop()
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonClientConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    tcpclnt = New TcpClient()
    tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.115", 40000)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSendData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' HERE IM TRYING TO WRITE DATA TO STREAM FROM TEXTBOX
    Dim msg As New System.IO.StringReader(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim msgstr As String = msg.ReadToEnd
    Dim msgbyte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgstr)
    stream.Write(msgbyte, 0, msgbyte.Length)
End Sub


End Class
```

What I'm trying to do: I create server, then press button `ButtonClientConnection' and create and connect client (TcpClient). That works - I get strings`Server started`and`Client connected` in textbox1.

Now I want to do: put some text in textbox2, press button `ButtonSendData` and transmit this data from client to server through the stream and write this data to another textbox (textbox3).
My attempts are here in the code, but nothing is happens - As I see in debugger I write some data in stream, but can't read it because my code for reading data from stream executes only 1 time at client connection.

**How to read data permanently? And write it correctly to stream by pressing `ButtonSendData`?**
I made some workaround and it looks like it stuck at line:

```
i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

Code stops here and can't go further in this thread.

Comment: [**`NetworkStread.Read()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) blocks the calling thread until there's something to receive, so execution should continue when you send data.

Comment: @VisualVincent Aha! So I just send data incorrectly? Can you take a look at my `ButtonSendData_Click` function. Maybe I do it in another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending data through the wrong stream. `stream` is the server's stream, but you have no stream for `tcpclnt`.

Try this:

```
Dim clientstream As NetworkStream

Private Sub ButtonClientConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    tcpclnt = New TcpClient()
    tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.115", 40000)
    clientstream = tcpclnt.GetStream()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSendData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim msgbyte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text)
    clientstream.Write(msgbyte, 0, msgbyte.Length)
End Sub
```

As you see I have also removed the `StringReader` because it was completely unnecessary. You were creating it only to read it back to a string again, where you can just get the bytes from `TextBox2.Text` directly instead.

Comment: Visual Vincent, thank you again for so fast reply! I remove surplus lines in `ButtonSendData_Click`. I comment stream definition in `Sub ConnectionListener` but it still stuck at line  `i = clientstream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)` . Can you watch it one more time please! I add all edits in code in my question.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Nonono, you're not supposed to change _**anything else**_ than what I show in my answer. You need the two different streams: client and server.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : If the _**server**_ receives from the _**client stream**_ then you will never get the data that you send from the _**client stream**_. The client sends to the server stream and vice versa. -- You ought to divide this into two applications (or at least two forms) so that you don't mix them up so easily.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Here's a small illustration of how it needs to be divided: http://imgur.com/KCnQ6m3

Comment: I got it! Now it works and I can send and collect data! One last problem: I can't understand how to display received data only once: I put text in textbox2, press SendData, it writes to `clientstream`. Then `stream` became active (we return to ConnectionListener` function), it read data from `stream` and... and what? In my loop now it puts this text in TextBox3 (yep, it is what I want) but it is infinity loop. How to say him to read `stream` always and if its not empty put data to TextBox3? Or it's better to ask another question about this?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Update the question with your new code, please.

Comment: I GOT IT! I just add `i = stream.Read(...)` inside this infinity loop, so he always waits for the next data! Thank you very much!

Give me an advice please: do I need to post correct code in question now? Instead of this incorrect code?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : Well yes, you have to wait for new data :). And no, you don't need to post your new code. I will do a rollback to the previous edit though since others might misinterpret the current one and my answer.