# VB.net Open Telnet connection w/ Userinput as Password and Read XML Response

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, telnet, putty

I am trying to get some XML data from a third party app. To acquire this data, I can Putty, using Telnet, into the IP Address with a specific port. Once the connection is open, all I need to do is type in

```
<StageDisplayLogin>password</StageDisplayLogin>
```

Once that is submitted. All of my return XML data pops up in my Putty Window which I will end up parsing into variables very often. I tried replicating this with many different solutions in VB.net and I couldn't get anything to work. Here it what I was currently working on. I already tried a few TCP Client projects like the one listed here

[Using streams through TcpClient and TcpServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044061/using-streams-through-tcpclient-and-tcpserver)

I would like to do this with my own app not using putty. This is my latest try using a POST method instead to see if that might work. I can enter everything but the program hangs from what I am guessing is a timeout. You wouldn't be able to simulate this since you don't have my software (ProPresenter) but is this the correct way to simulate a Putty Telnet session? The user will input their IP Address, their port and their password. This program will stay open as the third party program updates the session at any data changes.

```
<Window x:Name="vWindow" x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:vPresenter"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FF1E2328" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="137*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="vIPAddress" Margin="165,43,173,211.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="IP Address" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="vPort" Margin="165,91,173,163.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Port" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="vPassword" Margin="165,137,173,117.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PPData" Margin="27,43,312,146.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Data" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="151,-6,152,251.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="vMixPresenter" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button x:Name="ConntectButton" Content="Connect!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Background="DarkGreen" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="SendButton" Content="Send!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Background="DarkGreen" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" Click="Button2_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ServerText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,249,0,-16.6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="42" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="100"/>


</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the VB File

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MainWindow

Private Server As TcpListener = Nothing
Private ServerThread As Thread = Nothing
Dim tcpclnt As TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream
Dim clientstream As NetworkStream

Public Shared bytes(1024) As Byte
Public Shared data As String = Nothing

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 45678)
    ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionListener)
    ServerThread.IsBackground = True
    ServerThread.Start()
    ServerText.Text = "Server started!"
End Sub

Public Sub ConnectionListener()
    Try
        Server.Start()


        While True
            Dim myClient As TcpClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf SomeClientActions)
            T.Start(myClient)
            'Invoke(Sub() ServerText.Text = ServerText.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Client connected")
            Console.WriteLine("1")

            ' HERE IM TRYING TO READ DATA FROM STREAM
            stream = myClient.GetStream()
            Dim i As Int32
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            Console.WriteLine("1.5")
            While True
                Console.WriteLine("2")
                ' Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                'Invoke(Sub() TextBox3.Text = "Received: {0}" + data)
                Console.WriteLine("received" & data)

                ' Process the data sent by the client.

                Dim msg As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                ' Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length)
                'Invoke(Sub() TextBox3.Text = "Sent: {0}" + data)
                Console.WriteLine("sent" & data)

                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            End While


            myClient.Close()
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Server Error")
    End Try
    Application.ExitThread()

End Sub

Private Sub SomeClientActions(ByVal client As Object)
    ' ... do something with "client" in here ...
    ' MAYBE SOME CODE HERE?..
End Sub


Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    tcpclnt = New TcpClient()
    tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.1.101", 45678)
    clientstream = tcpclnt.GetStream()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim msgbyte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PPData.Text)
    clientstream.Write(msgbyte, 0, msgbyte.Length)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You better show us your `TcpClient` code and describe us, what's wrong with it. Trying HTTP `POST` does not make any sense.

Comment: Ill update the code above. I think I might have found the problem with this code I am about to update. I didn't realize it was for a Windows Form and Not WPF. Not sure if that is causing it not to work.

Comment: That code is for Telnet server. You are implementing a Telnet client.